# What happens to ICF in primary aldosteronism?

Tags: physiology, pathophysiology, dehydration

There is contradictory information in my two textbooks,

**As per Kaplan Physiology 2018,**

> There is gain of isotonic fluid, because aldosteronism cause Na+ retention and water follow, so osmolality doesn't change and no pulling/pushing of water to ICF from ECF because osmolality is near normal.
>   hence, *ICF & Blood osmolality - No change*

**As per Guyton Hall Textbook of Medical Physiology (SA edition 2, Pg 54 table 6-2)**

> Plasma Na+ rises, ECF increase, but here(contrast to kaplan) ICF decrease

Now I'm thinking that fluid might have flowed from ICF to ECF on account of Na+ rise but then idea of Kaplan will contradict.

I'm confused here.

Comment: What is the context for each piece of text? Are they talking about identical physiological scenarios?

Comment: yes I think so, they're talking in general